# Getting an existing menu for tkinter Toplevel

Tags: python, tkinter

I know how to create and set menus for tkinter Toplevel windows, but I'm struggling to find any information on how to **get** a window's menu bar. What I'd like to do is dynamically add options to the menu, so I need to do something like:

```
menubar = self.getMenu()
menubar.add_cascade(...)
```

Where `self` is a Toplevel window. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [cget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.cget-method) method, which can be used to get any of the configured options:

```
menu = self.cget("menu")
```